# Post table row of checkboxed column

Tags: php, forms, html-table

I have a table like this

```
<form method="post" action="url">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="first_name"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="2"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="second_name"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="3"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="third_name"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

then, when I post this form, I want to send only `cbox[]` and `name[]` of rows that have checkbox selected

Comment: You want to submit via PHP? you could attach the the action as PHP or use an Ajax to parse the information.

Comment: Share your try and error if any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to

```
      <form id ='myform' method="post" action="url">
        <input type='hidden' id='checkboxs' name='checkboxs'>
        <input type='hidden' id='names' name='names'>
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="1"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name1" value="first_name"></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="2"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name2" value="second_name"></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="3"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name3" value="third_name"></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="send" onclick="submitValue()"/>
    </form>
```

and add function

```
        function submitValue()
        {
            var checkboxs = [];
            var names = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
               checkboxs[i] = $(this).val();
               names[i] = $('input[name=name'+(i+1)+']').val();
            });
            console.log(checkboxs);
            console.log(names);
            $('#checkboxs').val(checkboxs);
            $('#names').val(names);
            $('#myform').submit();
        }
```

your value in checkboxs and names
Hope this help